# BlackBerry Trackpad Scrolling Issues

Tags: html, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I have problem scrolling using trackpad. Below is the example that I tried from pdf on  WebWorks focus navigation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,width=device-width,user-    
scalable=no,target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<style>
.list
{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.list:hover
{
  background-color:red;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a class="list" x-blackberry-focusable="true" href="http://www.rim.com">Link to RIM</a>
<a class="list" x-blackberry-focusable="true" href="http://www.blackberry.com">Link to 
BlackBerry</a>
```

When I try to scroll using trackpad nothing happens. The link are supposed to be highlighted red but nothing happens. I have my config.xml and  is in it.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What device/OS version are you testing this with? I tried the above code in the browser using my 9900 running 7.1.x and it works as expected.

What version of the WebWorks SDK are you using?

Have you added the following into config.xml?

Comment: I tested it on Curve 9630 running on BB 5 and Torch 9800 running on BB 6. I have <rim:navigation mode="focus" /> in the config.xml.